# DatGridCell get Reset when applying a custom style

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I have a DataGrid that contains Data and I wanna make all data in that dataGrid Centered to its DataGridCell that it is in.

So I did as below (xaml file)

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_Prj.View.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:col="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_Prj.View"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WPF_Prj.ViewModel"
    Title="[Portfolio] MainWindow" Height="500" Width="800">


<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <DataGrid x:Name="datagrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False"
            Width="Auto" Margin="5,5,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" CellEditEnding="datagrid_CellEndEditing">

        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <vm:PositiveConverter x:Key="PositiveConverter"/>                
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn                             Header="Name"           Binding="{Binding Name}"                                    IsReadOnly="True"   Width="Auto"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn                             Header="Owned Qty"      Binding="{Binding OwnedQty}"                                IsReadOnly="True"   Width="Auto"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="_UnitCost"          Header="Unit Cost"      Binding="{Binding UnitCost}"            IsReadOnly="True"                       Width="Auto"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="_MarketCost"        Header="Market Cost"    Binding="{Binding MarketCost}"          IsReadOnly="True"                       Width="Auto"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn     Header="Ordered Qty"    Binding="{Binding OrderedQty,       Mode=TwoWay }"                                 IsReadOnly="False"  Width="Auto">
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" >
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ColorCost}" Value="-1">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Moccasin"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ColorCost}" Value="1">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="GreenYellow"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn   Header="Confirmed Qty"  Binding="{Binding ConfirmedQty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay }" IsReadOnly="True"   Width="Auto"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
    <StackPanel Name="ButtomsZone" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button x:Name="YellOrders"  Content="Simulate Orders" Width="125" FontFamily="Fire Code" Click="YellOrders_Click" Margin="18,0" Height="25"/>
        <Button x:Name="Confirm"   Content="Confirm Orders"  Width="125" FontFamily="Fire Code" Click="Confirm_Click" Margin="25,0" IsEnabled="False"/>            
        <ComboBox>
            <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">Prioritize cheap goods</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Prioritize expensive goods</ComboBoxItem>    
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

So As the picture below shows, all the data are stretched and center aligned except for the `Ordered Qty` for which I tried to reforce the alignement but no success.

[image]

The question is how coud I make that column stretched and center its content? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting CellStyle explicitly on that column, which means that it doesn't use the implicit DataGridCell style you defined in DataGrid.Resources.

It's easy to fix in either of two ways: Either add those two alignment setters to the style for "Ordered Qty", or, better, use the `BasedOn` attribute to *base* that style on the default style, which will cause it to inherit everything the default style has:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style 
        TargetType="DataGridCell" 
        BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}"
        >
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ColorCost}" Value="-1">
```

If you add something else to the default cell style next week, it'll get included automatically in the specialized style for "Ordered Qty".

## Update: What's going on with the alignment?

The value shown in the cell is text, which is displayed in a TextBox or TextBlock. The text *within* the TextBox or TextBlock is left-aligned by default. So you have to set `TextBlock.TextAlignment`, which will be inherited by the TextBox or TextBlock, and will cause it to center its own content.

By default, that TextBox or TextBlock is stretched to fill the full width of the DataGridCell, because that's what a DataGridCell does with its content. You don't need any of those HorizontalAlignment setters. They're redundant. I'd remove them, for that reason: I don't like leaving no-op code in place, because next year I or somebody else will revisit the code and may waste time thinking it's there for a reason.

In some list controls, like a ListBox, item content is left aligned and you may need to set `HorizontalContentAlignment` on the ListBox. That's not the case with DataGrid. In fact, If you want to see something strange, try this for your implicit DataGridCellStyle:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Here, the control displaying the text is only as wide as its content. It's still centering the content, but you can't tell, because there's no space on either side. Also, the lines look funny.

Comment: Thx that resolved the prob, but why it didn't take account with `HorizontalAlignment` even set in that column it self ?

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd See update. HorizontalAlignment has no effect on anything here.

Comment: Many Thanks Clear. That made me cleaning my Code. Great